# NServiceBus 3.0.0 to 3.2.6 upgrade Bus.Reply no longer handled

Tags: nservicebus

i've checked all the web but since this is pretty much a newer version of nservicebus, i'm not sure if anyone has encountered this yet.

since upgrading from version 3.0.0 to 3.2.5 (and/or 3.2.6).. whenever we do a Bus.Reply to send back a response to the client (whilst the client uses a send().register...), the client doesn't seem to handle the incoming reply.. we had an input queue containing the replied message but the message stays there and no one picks it up. (and you guessed it.. no errors are thrown)

i checked the samples (fullduplex, asyncpagesmvc3) but they seem to look the same.. and oddly.. they worked.

anything i should be taking note of? 
btw the queues have the proper permissions set to them... and this whole reply thing works well in 3.0.0 (and even when i tried reverting back from 3.2.6 to 3.0.0)

any thoughts? tnx!

Comment: Nvm.. we added this code just like in the sample, inside the call to start: 
"() => Configure.Instance.       ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install()"

what is it for anyway??? :/

Comment: It will make sure that the installers are run when you start the bus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working on web applications, maybe you can try this during your bus initialization ?

**Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn().Install()**